# Why is $dq=\rho_s a d\theta 2 \pi a \sin\theta $ in the semi-sphere?and $E_z=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0dE_z$ not $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

There is a semi-spherical equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2,$ and $z>0$, and the surface charge density  is $\rho_s$. Please calculate the size and direction of the electric field generated by the charge distribution at the origin of the coordinates.

I have the solution of this question,but i don't understand some part of it,hoping someone can tell me why

[image]

$$dE_z=\frac{dq}{4\pi \epsilon_{0} a^2}\cos\theta=\frac{\rho_s a d\theta 2 \pi a \sin\theta}{4\pi \epsilon_{0} a^2}\cos\theta$$

$$E_z=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0dE_z=\frac{\rho_s}{4\epsilon_{0}}$$ so the $$\vec E=-\vec u_z \frac{\rho_s}{4\epsilon_{0}}$$

My questions are

1. why is $dq=\rho_s a d\theta 2 \pi \, a \,\sin\theta ?$
2. $E_z=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0dE_z$, why is not $E_z=\int^{\pi}_0dE_z$, isn't it a semi-sphere?

Comment: $a^2\sin\theta d\thetad\phi$ is the surface element of the sphere, they just integrated over $\phi\in(0,2\pi)$ from rotational symmetry. In spherical coordinates, $\theta\in(0,\pi)$, so the hemisphere is parametrised for $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$.